# Adbrite not showing up anything. Possible code error?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm trying to run ads with AdBrite, and they have the worst support documentation.

Here's the code:

```
<!-- Begin: adBrite, Generated: 2011-11-13 20:07:03  -->
<script type="text/javascript">
var AdBrite_Title_Color = 'B3B3B3';
var AdBrite_Text_Color = '7F7F7F';
var AdBrite_Background_Color = 'E6E6E6';
var AdBrite_Border_Color = 'B3B3B3';
var AdBrite_URL_Color = '4C4C4C';
try{var AdBrite_Iframe=window.top!=window.self?2:1;var AdBrite_Referrer=document.referrer==''? document.location:document.referrer;AdBrite_Referrer=encodeURIComponent(AdBrite_Referrer);}catch(e){var AdBrite_Iframe='';var AdBrite_Referrer='';}
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,83,67,82,73,80,84));document.write(' src="http://ads.adbrite.com/mb/text_group.php?sid=2047312&zs=3132305f363030&ifr='+AdBrite_Iframe+'&ref='+AdBrite_Referrer+'" type="text/javascript">');document.write(String.fromCharCode(60,47,83,67,82,73,80,84,62));        </script>


<div><a target="_top" href="http://www.adbrite.com/mb/commerce/purchase_form.php?opid=2047312&afsid=1" style="font-weight:bold;font-family:Arial;font-size:13px;">Your Ad Here</a></div>
<!-- End: adBrite -->
```

This should be showing up a blank ad with a link that says "your ad here", but nothing show up.

Comment: it's showing a banner on right with a link "Advertise on this site"...clear you cache and try again!

Comment: I've tried every method to delete the cache. Still nothing. I'm using chrome.

Comment: Boy do I have egg on face.   Apparently Adblock blocks it.  I had to disable adblock to see it.

Comment: Add your answer and select it as correct.  That will close out this question without your account being penalized.  Also, please don't ever ask questions like "my website is broken here's the link [spam] what's wrong?"  They'll get closed.

Comment: press CTRL+SHIFT+R to reload a page without the cache

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait several hours before it works, and after that dont you have to approve adds on adbrite?